# VSCode Default Shell pointing to wrong python environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

On my system i have both python 3.8 and python 3.9 installed.

In side my settings.json is the following:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Program Files\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe"
}
```

When i run my python file in VSCode, all is well.   However, i want to open a terminal window to create a virtual environment using the above python install.   When select 'Terminal: Create new integrate terminal', a command terminal is opened (i have the default set to cmd).

When i then execute *'python --version'*. nothing is printed out.

when i execute *'py --version'*, i see *'Python 3.9.0'*.

If do a *'where python'*, i see *'C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe'*

If i do a *'where py'*, i see  *'C:\Windows\py.exe'*

So it doesn't look like i can use the VS Code terminal window to create a virtual environment for the target python version i am currently running in my workspace because it is not the python that is on the path in that terminal window.   Does anyone know if this is the expected behavior?

Comment: A possible workaround is to open VSCode from an environment. Running "code" from your cmd. Maybe the right paths are set later for vscode

Comment: @mike01010 -It is recommended that you check the Python environment variables and restart your computer.

Answer (score -1):

You can choose the environment for which python version should be used, i have python 3.8 and .9 installed too. But i only let vs code use 3.9 . You can do this in the command palette or in settings. Also when importing a file, always check that it it the same python version you want so theres no clashing between versions. This could be one problem of why you have your error as stated.

Comment: yes, that is correct.  and as mentioned, it uses the right version to run..but when you open a shell, it doesn't set the path with that version..so if you create pip install or create a virtual environment, you could be creating it using an unintended version.  that's the issue